# How Would The Listed Towers Be Described?

Tags: internal-consistency, worldbuilding-process, architecture, alternate-earth

In some foreseeable future, we have had transdimensional historians studying alternate Earths with multiple different points of departure, sometimes within the same Earth.  In one of them, the Black Death was so virile that European monarchy was driven to extinction, leading to an altogether different reason for World War I to happen, if not on a different timescale.  The focus of this question is a postwar America that created a skyline different from ours.  Whereas places like New York City and Chicago have skyscrapers that are unique not only to one city but also from each other, postwar American cities in this alternate Earth are more homogeneous.  An alternate New York city would have at least a dozen towers of identical shape and size.  So homogeneous are they that our transdimensional historians have categorized them by the following types based on shape and size:

1. India Tower
2. Miaopolis
3. Madinat al-Hareer
4. Kingdom Tower
5. Azerbaijan Tower
6. Bionic Tower
7. Nakheel Tower
8. The Illinois
9. Al Jaber Tower
10. Aeropolis 2001
11. Dubai City Tower

The shapes and sizes of the listed types can be found in this link below:

[World's Tallest Buildings Ever Proposed](https://orig00.deviantart.net/efaf/f/2015/299/e/d/tallest_planned_buildings___chart_by_jaysimons-d9efexu.jpg)

The trouble our transdimensional historians would have of popularizing on those types in a textbook or wiki back home is how to describe them.  How would they describe the towers listed above, using the link provided?

***To provide a clear example, if I were a transdimensional historian looking at a silhouette of Sky City in Changsha from a distance, I would describe it as a narrow wedding cake with four or five layers.***

Comment: Historians will read the name of the building from the sign at the main entrance.

Comment: I would describe them all as big heaps of bricks.

Comment: World war I happened in a future... black death was virile... do you mind clarifying such concepts?

Comment: Are these 'historians' looking into the para-past? Or across at the para-present? Or both?

Comment: @Renan  That is not at all creative.

Comment: @L.Dutch  Specifying them is not the point here.

Comment: I need to vote to put this on hold until you can help me understand why it isn't too story-based (OT:TSB).  Only you and your story know how a "transdimensional being" thinks.  I can tell you what shape-in-the-cloud description I might have, but what's my description compared to yours?  Even if you describe your transdimensional beings to us, they're still your beings - your story - and you'll always know how they think better than we can.  I should think one thing is true: such beings wouldn't imagine human-centric descriptions.

Comment: And a note to everyone who voted POB.  POB ***does not have the same meaning here that it does on other SE sites.***  It can't, otherwise no question about magic could be answered.  It's important to understand when each VTC reason can be used.  There are posts on Meta that help explain all this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I feel quite strongly that *invention*, in the sense of rhetorical invention, is the job of the author. The question is not asking for information, is not asking for criticism, is asking directly for the members of the community to do the author's job.

Comment: @JBH  Uh...why would you think that "transdimensional" equals aliens?

Comment: @AlexP  I wouldn't do this if I do know how to describe them.  But the towers listed in the post are shaped so unconventionally that I just don't.

Comment: Let's take for example № 10, Aëropolis 2001. It has the shape of a columnar crystal made of several unequal and fused triangular prisms, with slanted upper surfaces, rocketing towards the sky. Or № 3, the Silken City: an agglomeration of barely touching prisms with sharp edges, surging from a collection of much lower constructions shaped like an early modern polygonal fortress. № 2, Miapolis, is made of two slender half-cones joined at the base and at several widely spaced levels by squat cylinders, and topped with two gigantic divergent horns in remembrance of the architect's master.

Comment: @AlexP  This is exactly the sort of thing I'm aiming at.  Thank you.

Comment: Because they're not humans from my own dimention.  More to the point, why would transdimensional beings think something looked like "an early modern polygonal fortress?"  That's what it would look like to us, not them.  What's their background?  What common objects from their past could be used to describe these towers?

Comment: And "dimention" could be taken either way... it's been one of those days...

Comment: @JBH  If these transdimensional historians were aliens, I would have said so.

Comment: Is there an argument?  How curious...  I can't edit a comment after 5 minutes, so there's nothing I can do.  Transdimensional humans, aliens, ambulatory plants, rocks that burp... It doesn't change the nature of your question unless you specify that something that isn't us (transdimensional) has our background in culture.  Have you said so?  No... I'm left to guess that something that we aren't is alien - a common definition.  If I'm wrong, please update your question.  It won't bother me.

Answer (score 1):

Architecture is my field, and one thing I know about buildings is that they are rarely simply about the building itself - they always follow the forms of their culture and society.

When describing buildings of the past it is incomplete to only describe their physical characteristics - what use would such information have to us with abilities greater than the past? Instead, we view them as emblems of society, markers of places in history.

In this regard, the Eiffel Tower has always been viewed as an emblem of industrialism, that of the new world brought about by the new industrial revolution. It's iron detailing, bolt-together aesthetic is a part of this.

The Twin Towers in New York were symbols of capitalism - Yamasaki designed 2 main towers (amongst actually a complex of smaller towers) instead of one large grand tower to symbolise proportions of equality and stability, essential in the workings of capitalism.

All designers who design buildings are a part of their time, and although limited by technology, their forms functions and integration in society are consistently built within their designs.

This is the context in which historians have viewed buildings in the past, and will again view buildings in the future. This provides the most relevant view to future peoples, as it is also a measure of human culture and what it has gone through to become what it is for them in their present.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  At all.